# Triggering function from one master spreadsheet in other spreadsheet documents

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a bunch of spreadsheets containing financial forecast. At the end of each month I make a copy to lock in the months forecast in every sheet. This works well. The problem is that I have to open all the sheets separately in order to activate the script in each sheet. So I was wondering if there is a way to trigger the script via a button from a master spreadsheet that looks something like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YA6twVP3_oSJttcLx5JRdm8TO01zKFr2k_D9lrlc1eE/edit#gid=0

The script I'd like to trigger looks like this:

```
function CopyMonth() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let ss = sh.duplicateActiveSheet();
  let name = ss.getRange("a26").getDisplayValue();
  
  ss.setName(name);
 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());
    rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 1), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

The time and date I lock the forecast varies so it cannot be activated by a specific time or something like that.

The marked duplicate does not address my issue. The subject referenced to explains how to create a button to run a script. I'm asking how to run a script I've made in one document from an entirely different document. My problem is that I have 8 document I have to open and press a button today to run my script. I want to be able to run the scrip in all 8 documents from a master document instead.

Comment: You could try writing a script for this. Maybe use python or powershell? I doubt excel has the functionality to open documents. Worst case scenario you can make an autoclicker.

Comment: You could run scripts from [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that all the spreadsheets you want to process are in the same folder, with no other spreadsheets in that folder or its subfolders, you can use something like this:

```js
/**
* Makes a values only copy of the first tab in all
* spreadsheets in a folder and its subfolders.
*/
function insertValuesOnlyMonthTabInManySpreadsheets() {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 14 December 2022
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/74801764/13045193
  const folderName = '...put folder name here...';
  const _action = (file) => {
    const ss = getSpreadsheetFromFile_(file);
    if (!ss) {
      return;
    }
    const firstTab = ss.getSheets()[0];
    const tabName = firstTab.getRange('A26').getDisplayValue();
    let newTab;
    try {
      newTab = firstTab.copyTo(ss);
      newTab.setName(tabName);
    } catch (error) {
      handleError_(error);
      if (!newTab) {
        return;
      }
    }
    const rangeToCopyAsValuesOnly = firstTab.getDataRange();
    rangeToCopyAsValuesOnly.copyTo(newTab.getRange(1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });
    console.log(`Processed '${ss.getName()}'.`);
  };

  const folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
  processFilesInFolderRecursively_(folder, _action, handleError_);
}
```

For that to work, you will need to paste the `getSpreadsheetFromFile_()`, `processFilesInFolderRecursively_()` and `handleError_()` functions in the script project. You can get them from the [processFilesInFolderRecursively_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/182948899?msgid=182993974) script.